# Advice on application design: Batch audio processing via AWS

Tags: architecture, amazon-web-services, batch-processing

I need to build an audio processing application. The high level workflow is:

1. User uploads a batch of audio files
2. The files are processed by an executable
3. The user is able to download the processed files.

I'm a javascript and php developer and I'm not well versed with architecture and infrastructure concerns. I would imagine that AWS has a product or service that would help with a lot of the heavy lifting, but I'm not sure which of the many AWS services I should be researching.

Here's my question: Does AWS provide a specific product tailored to this type of application? If so, which product?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, No. You can host your application on EC2, but at its core its just a VPS. You do have the advantage of paying for only the time that you need. But if you need your application available all the time, you need at least some instances running.

If you are processing large batches of audio files you may be able to take advantage of the elasticity of the infrastructure to optimize cost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No:  AWS offers products and services to help solve your problem - *in the same way that Home Depot offers products and services that will solve your housing problems* - but you still need to take the pieces to put together a solution.

But, for example, in your scenario here are just a few of AWS's offerings and how you might use them:

Amazon S3 could work for a place to store those files when they are uploaded, and after they are processed.

Amazon Glacier could be used for really inexpensive file archiving of files, before or after processing.

On or more EC2 instances, running the OS flavor of your choice can host the executable that will actually process the files.

Amazon SQS and SNS can can be used to provide queuing and notifications services, between different parts of the system i.e. to build a queue of files to be processed, and allow for multiple worker jobs to read files from the queue and process them.

Amazon SES caould be used for delivering email notifications about files being ready.